# Tikz: how to draw a horizontal line between 2 nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (1) {Node};
\node [draw, below = of 1] (1) {Long text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to draw the dashed line between the nodes and make a padding 1cm from the borders?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An option without `calc` library, using just the perpendicular coordinate system and `xshift`; the main idea is to place an auxiliary coordinate midway both nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
  node [draw] (1) {Node}
  node [draw, below = 2cm of 1] (2) {Long text}
  (1.south) -- coordinate (aux) (1.south|-2.north);
\draw[dashed] 
  ([xshift=-1cm]2.north west|-aux) -- ([xshift=1cm]2.north east|-aux);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the aux coordinate, is that means the midway between two nodes? why we need to use (1.south|-2.north)? I guess (2.north) is enough.

Comment: @lucky1928 1) Yes. 2) To guarantee the line is horizontal in case nodes have different shapes.

Answer (score 4):

Using the calc library, you can use the coordinates of your points to draw a line.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    %coordinate calculation
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (1) {Node};
\node [draw, below = of 1] (2) {Long text};
\draw[dashed] let \p1=(1),\p2=(2),\p3=(2.north west),\p4=(2.north east) in 
    (\x3-1cm,{(\y1+\y2)/2}) -- (\x4+1cm,{(\y1+\y2)/2});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

\x3 is the x coordinate of the \p3 (upper left corner of your second box).
{(\y1+\y2)/2} is the mid point between your two boxes.  The braces are important.

Comment: cool, so \p1 = (\x1,\y1). does \P1 = (\X1,\Y1)?

Comment: @lucky1928 No, the let command calls 4 macro, \n for a number, \p for a point and \x \y the coordinate of the point.  Page 160 of the PGF manual (version 3.0.1a)